# Site Editor: Pattern previews too small?

Tags: editor, previews

I created a Block Theme, and when viewing my patterns in the "Site Editor", they're displayed too narrow in the preview:

[image]

When activating the Twenty Twenty Four block theme, they are displayed correctly (meaning filling the entire space).

Anyone has a clue what is missing in my block theme?

Appreciate any hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! Should anyone run into a similar issue:

In my case, I ignorantly had global `iframe` styles that interfered with the preview.